# Check if a string consists of exactly 5 digits in Java

Tags: java, regex

In a Java application I need to check if a given string

- contains only digits 0-9 and
- is exactly five digits long

My first attempt is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String testString = "000000";
    String myPattern = "\\d{5}";

    Pattern validCharacterPattern = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
    Matcher matcher = validCharacterPattern.matcher(testString);
    boolean b = matcher.find();

    if (b) System.out.println("Valid");
    else System.out.println("Invalid");

}
```

However the above expression is also true for e.g. `123456`. What do I need to change?

Comment: "*However the above expression is also true for e.g. `123456`*" doesn't seem true. `"123456".matches("\\d{5}")` returns `false` to me.

Comment: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ Says that `\d{5}` works for matches. Perhaps you should paste your actual code, as this seems contrived.

Comment: word boundary regex `\\b`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975644/regular-expression-to-match-exactly-5-digits

Comment: I tested the above expression for 123456, just to be sure.  It is not true.  This question is in error, as is every single answer on this page.

Comment: Please red the documentation of String.matches: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Robert It would be really nice (and would stop your question from getting closed) if you would read what everyone has been saying and post an edit, or delete the question.

Comment: Your code is working for me: http://jdoodle.com/a/65 (click execute)

Comment: I have reworked my question and provided the specific code snippet.

Comment: "What do I need to change?"  You could go back to the version you posted the first time, which worked great!  Or change `matcher.find` to `matcher.matches`.

Comment: Is it a must to use `matcher`? Can't you iterate all the characters and check one by one with a counter?

Comment: Funny thing is that answer to your current version of your question was its previous version :)

Comment: lol now suddenly using pattern matcher..

Comment: It really annoys me when people post questions about code that's different from the code that's actually causing them the problem.  "Tell me what I'm doing wrong, in the code that I _didn't_ post."

Comment: @DavidWallace At some level they have to edit it a little bit. They can't just dump a million code files. But when they minimize it for a question they should actually..... run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sake of completeness (even though the question has changed completely)

```
boolean b = matcher.find();
```

This will match if the regex is contained somewhere in the matching string. If you use `matcher.matches` you will get the expected behaviour, where it must match the ENTIRE string.

Alternatively you can skip the compile step(not recommended if this regex is going to be used several times.) altogether and just write:

```
String regex = "\\d{5}";
String test = "123456";
if(test.matches(regex)){ ... };
```

Which is essentially what you had in the original question.

Comment: Sorry for having caused this much of a confusion. That answer pretty much does it.

Comment: @Robert Don't ask any question before trying it yourself. Please...

Comment: I like to call these types of questions, that *completly* change only after all answers have been posted, as "Sixth Sense" questions. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong

**However the above expression is also true for e.g. 123456. What do I need to change?**

Its `false` for `123456`.

---

Sample code:

```
    String s = "123456";
    String regex = "\\d{5}";
    if (s.matches(regex))
        System.out.println("found");
    else
        System.out.println("not found");
```

output

```
not found
```

---

Question has been edited. Now try with start and end in regex.

```
    String testString = "000000";
    String myPattern = "^(\\d{5})$";

    Pattern validCharacterPattern = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
    Matcher matcher = validCharacterPattern.matcher(testString);
    boolean b = matcher.find();

    if (b)
        System.out.println("Valid");
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid");
```

output:

```
Invalid
```

Comment: This regex means exactly the same as `"\\d{5}"` so this is not the solution.

Comment: OK we always give hints. A hint is sufficient for an intelligent guy as you.

Comment: I tried it 4 digits that why I posted it. I was just changing it but some one has done it already.

Comment: @Jesper try it yourself.

Comment: @Braj try this with `"123456".matches(regex)`, you'll see the result is `true`, exactly the problem that the original poster has - this will not match only exactly 5 digits.

Comment: Have a look at my post.

Comment: @Jesper **Sorry its returning `false`**

Comment: What nonsense what is wrong. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Ok, I tried it, the result is indeed `not found`. But if you try it with `"\\d{5}"` the result is also `not found`. Looks like the original question asker has something wrong.

Comment: OP wants : **However the above expression is also true for e.g. 123456. What do I need to change?**

Comment: Well, as we can see, the expression is **not** true for 123456. The original asker of the question is wrong.

Comment: Yes that what I want to know. Am I taking it wrong?

Comment: Yeah the question is wrong, that is why I voted to close the question. However, I don't see the point why `\\d{5}` should be replaced with `\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d` ==> it matches exactly the same, but it is just more tedious... what if you want to match exactly 25 digits, 200 digits etc. ;-)

Comment: I thought as per OP its not working then I tried with this pattern but later It come to know that [you know it.]:)

Comment: @Braj Assuming that the OP has run the code that he posted in a stackoverflow question is completely unreasonable. /sarcasm

Comment: @Cruncher I don't want to discuss more on this matter. I think its enough. :)